# Raspberry + Windows IoT - display sensor data + controls in browser

Tags: c#, web, raspberry-pi, windowsiot

first timer here!

Sorry if this question has been asked before. I tried to search but I can't really seem to find a solution. I'm just starting out development with Raspberry + Windows IoT. Before this I was mostly into android developement.

My question is kind of vague, I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. I'd prefer to code my apps in C#, if that matters. 
I didn't find a way to install a web server under Windows IoT, so I'm wondering how would someone go about displaying sensor data and some control buttons in a web based UI that interact with my c# code controlling LEDs or whatever?

I already found restup (https://github.com/tomkuijsten/restup) and based on the  couple of examples I've seen I think I could add web based controls with it to my app, but can I also use it to read sensor data from the Pi? Or do I need something else to achieve that? I'm a bit clueless in this area. Thanks in advance and sorry if my question doesn't belong here for some reason.

Comment: I am using iot-web https://www.nuget.org/packages/IotWeb/ and it is working well. It also supports web sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it based [restup](https://github.com/tomkuijsten/restup/tree/master/src/HeadedDemo). If you have been able to get sensor data from sensor device then what you need to do is:

1. Send request via browser, for example, "Read sensor data", looks like this:
   [image]
2. After pressing "Send" button, you will get request data in ProcessRequestAsync().
3. Parse the request data you will get your "Read sensor data" command, at this time, you can go to read sensor data and put these data into Http response.
4. After sending Http response, you will see the sensor data in the browser.

Note: You may need to modify the Http request parse logic in order to find out your specialized commands.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you can install a web server in Windows IoT. As you are from Android background, why don't you go for a java solution ?

1) Install Raspbian in Pi.

2) Create a simple restful based java application which can be run from command line. You don't have to install any java application server, you can build application with embedded server.

http://nikgrozev.com/2014/10/16/rest-with-embedded-jetty-and-jersey-in-a-single-jar-step-by-step/
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html

3) You can use Pi4J library to control GPIO pins.
   http://pi4j.com/example/control.html

If you want to publish asp.net based web application on Windows 10 IoT Core, then check below link

https://www.hackster.io/iddi/windows-10-iot-core-publish-asp-net-web-application-d9dcd4

Comment: the problem is I am forced to go with Windows IoT as it was a proposed subject for my BSc dissertation, and I accepted it without doing proper bakcground check on the options and capabilities of  Windows IoT, so I have to get up to speed on the subject fairly quick now. I realized since then working on a Linux based system would be a lot easier, but if I wanted to change my dissertation now I'd lose a semester, and that's something I would want.

Comment: *that's NOT something I would want.. Thank you for your input anyway! appreciated :)

Comment: Have you checked below link, hope it helps you !!
https://www.hackster.io/iddi/windows-10-iot-core-publish-asp-net-web-application-d9dcd4